# How do I get JavaScript to interact with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am doing a project in computing for school. I need to get my drag able jQuery box to interact with my traffic lights( my traffic lights are on a cycle) when the box touches i need to traffic light cycle to start, is this possible? any help would be much appreciated,

Here is my code so far;

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
var lights = ["red.png", "yellow.png", "green.png"]
var lightscentre = 0
var timer

function ChangeImage() {
clearTimeout(timer)
 if (++lightscentre == lights.length)
   lightscentre = 0

  document.images[0].src = lights[lightscentre]

   timer = setTimeout(LightCycle, 1000)
}
function LightCycle() {
 clearTimeout(timer)
 if (++lightscentre == lights.length)
 lightscentre = 0

  document.images[0].src = lights[lightscentre]

  timer = setTimeout(LightCycle, 1000)
}
function stopCycle() {
clearTimeout(timer)
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="red.png" name="nt1" width="130" height="175" alt="123">

   <form>
<input type="button" value="Go" name="Go" onclick="ChangeImage()">
  <input type="button" value="Stop" name="Stop" onclick="stopCycle()">
    </form>

 <head>

<style>
#makeMeDraggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$( init );

function init() {
  $('#makeMeDraggable').draggable();
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="content" style="height: 400px;">
  <div id="makeMeDraggable"> </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please, separate your JS code and HTML code. Also, I'd advice to create JSFiddle, so people can help you. Read this article before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Either you could do the function in Jquery, for the animation(?) or what you were planning. Else, you can convert Jquery variables in JS to use them in your functions. The best way would be to take any GET/POST and do those in Jquery and do everything else in JS, or the data fetching part.

Also, good luck with your project. Feel free to hit me up at @ev1stensberg ( twitter) and chat.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    var lights = ["red.png", "yellow.png", "green.png"]
    var lightsCentre = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function {
      window.location.reload()
    }, 3000);

    var turnOnTheLights = function(e) {
      e.preventDefaults();

    switch(lights) {
      case (document.getElementbyId('redLights').onClick == true) :
        return lights[0]

      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("hello"),

      }, 3000);

      case(document.getElementbyId('redLights').onClick == true &&
      return lights[0] == true) :

        return lights[1].
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log("I'm a terrible programmer");
        }, 3000)

        case(document.getElementbyId('redLights').onClick == true &&
        return lights[1] == true) :
        return clearInterval(timer)

        break;

        default: window.location.reload();

    }
return lights;
  }
var turnOffTheLights = function(e) {
e.preventDefaults();
  return window.setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Heyho"), 3000
  });

}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="red.png" id ="redLights" name="nt1" width="130" height="175" alt="123">

       <form>
    <input type="button" value="Go" name="Go" onclick="turnOnTheLights()">
      <input type="button" value="Stop" name="Stop" onclick="turnOffTheLights()">
        </form>

     <head>

    <style>
    #makeMeDraggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $( init );

    function init() {
      $('#makeMeDraggable').draggable();
    }

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="content" style="height: 400px;">
      <div id="makeMeDraggable"> </div>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I would make it something like this. I just changed the js, not the jquery. Also, revert the array indexes, they´re wrong. It may also contain buggs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use drag event:

```js
function init() {
  var $light = $('img');
  var $draggable = $('#makeMeDraggable').draggable({
    drag: function( event, ui ) {
      var light_offset = $light.offset();
      if (ui.offset.left < light_offset.left+$light.width() &&
          ui.offset.left + $draggable.width() > light_offset.left &&
          ui.offset.top + $draggable.height() > light_offset.top &&
          ui.offset.top < light_offset.top+$light.height()) {
          if (!timer) {
            LightCycle();
          }
      } else {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/0jeobskw/)